# Diff backup fails with error 3035 but log backup succeeds

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-internals

We have a SQL Server 2014 Enterprise where the DIFF backups fail. 
This is the error message we get:

> Msg 3035, Level 16, State 1, Server sqltest, Line 1
> Cannot perform a differential backup for database 'database1', because a current database backup  does not exsist. Perform a full database backup by reissuing BACKUP DATABASE, omitting the WITH  DIFFERENTIAL option.

After analysing the output of the following query we noticed that a third party tool was taking snapshot backups.

```
    select top 20 bs.type,bs.database_backup_lsn,bs.checkpoint_lsn,bs.backup_start_date,bs.is_snapshot,
    bs.is_copy_only,bs.user_name
    from dbo.backupset bs
    where bs.database_name = 'database1'
    order by backup_start_date desc
```

According to [Pinal Dave](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/04/19/sql-server-msg-3035-level-16-cannot-perform-differential-backup-database-sqlauthority-current-database-backup-not-exist/) these tools use VSS to take a backup which is not a normal full backup.

What I don't understand is why LOG backups succeed? To my knowledge, they are also based on the last FULL backup.
Can somebody explain this difference to me?

Comment: Is this for multiple or just a single database? Is this production? AFAIK the only way to get more data is to use a DAC connection in single user mode - if you're up for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A log backup is *not* based on the most recent full backup. It is based on the most recent log backup.

I.e., you can "skip" a full or differential backup when you restore log backups, as long as you have an unbroken chain of log backups.

As for your particular issue: Work with the backup software/vendor and see if you can make it perform the snapshot backups so they are seen as `COPY_ONLY` by SQL Server. Possibly a setting in your backup software.